# Using myreader.read() two times in vb. Net using and condition

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I'm working on attendance management project using access database and it stores the name, attendance status, date and course code of a particular day.

I used myreader.read() condition to check if duplicate date exists and it worked fine but the problem is when I use course code with condition as If myreader.read() and myreader1.read()
Con.close()
Messagebox.show(course and date already present)

and I have course code in a combobox. It works fine for the first time but after that when I change date, it says the course code already present. Is there any way to filter different courses corresponding to a particular date?

Comment: if you can, please show your code because the answer is not very clear to me. Use Ctrl + K to properly format it

Comment: Really need to see code.  That said, DB data access and retrieval tends to be one of the more heavy overheads of apps, consider there could be a case for reading your query results to an in memory collection of some type once (eg DataTable) then run your processes on that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.